Flutter building with wrong compileSdkVersion
I'm trying to update the compileSdkVersion from 33 to 34 in my Flutter project.
I changed the android/app/build.gradle file, ran
flutter clean
flutter pub get

I built the new appbundle but when I upload it to Play Store it still identifies as compileSdkVersion 33.
This is the build.gradle I'm using.
https://pastebin.com/aAWQRRRJ
What am I missing?

It would be best to update targetSdkVersion

@HitarthChhunchha that was it, thank you!

Thanks to @Hitarth Chhunchha in the comments I was able to find the solution.
In the android/app/build.gradle file, I changed this line
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion

to this
targetSdkVersion 34

and this solved my issue.
Useful if you need to manually handle the target SDK version without upgrading Flutter.
